# Problems reading configuation using Spring cloud config with GIT

Tags: git, spring-boot, spring-cloud, configserver

I am following the Spring cloud config sample from spring.io. Trying to read a property from properties file by using git. I tried the suggestions given in Stackoverflow for similar questions but it did not work. Any insights to help solve this issue?

BTW, I am using Windows 10, JDK 8, Spring Boot 2.0.4

This is my config in server side. I tried with both git and native but no luck:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active:
    # - native
    - development

---
spring:
  profiles: native
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          search-locations:
          - C:/config-repo
--- 

spring:        
  profiles: development

# using git  

  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: file:///C:/config-repo

---

server:
  port: 8888   

config.properties file exists in C:\config-repo
 contents of config.properties:

        message = "Hello Spring Boot config"
```

**Config Client configuration:**

```
    public class SpringCloudconfigClientApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(SpringCloudconfigClientApplication.class, args);
        }
    }

    @RefreshScope
    @RestController
    class MessageRestController {

        @Value("${message:Hello default}")
        private String message;

        @RequestMapping("/message")
        String getMessage() {
            return this.message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured the client application name should match the properties file name. I am not sure if this is a requirement to have the file name matching with properties/yml file in config server.

**Client side bootstrap.yml:**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: config

  cloud:
    config:
      uri:
      - http://localhost:8888
```

**application.yml:**

```
management:
  endpoints: 
    web: 
      exposure: 
        include:
        - '*'
```

**Config Server application.yml:**

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active:
    # - native
    # - development
    - remote_repo

---
spring:
  profiles: native
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          search-locations:
          - C:/config-repo
--- 

spring:        
  profiles: development

# using git/local file system 

  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: file:///C:/config-repo

---

spring:        
  profiles: remote_repo

# using git/local file system 

  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/<<YOUR_USER_NAME>>/cloud-config-repo
          skip-ssl-validation: true
          username: <<YOUR_USER_NAME>>
          password: <<YOUR_REPO_PASSWORD>>

---

server:
  port: 8888
```

Comment: It is required, that's the only key config server has to know what configuration to find.